# How to select a subset of rows based on a specific range in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains information about commits.

The dataset is quite similar to this:

| commit | bug |
| --- | --- |
| sha_1 | Stable |
| sha_2 | Stable |
| sha_3 | Stable |
| sha_4 | Increase |
| sha_5 | Stable |
| sha_6 | Stable |
| sha_7 | Decrease |
| sha_8 | Stable |
| sha_9 | Decrease |
| sha_10 | Decrease |
| sha_11 | Increase |
| sha_12 | Stable |

I need to select the range of rows that contains "Increase" and "Decrease" (or vice versa) and are contained inside two commits, "Stable".

For instance, according to the previous example, the output should be the following:

| commit | bug |
| --- | --- |
| sha_3 | Stable |
| sha_4 | Increase |
| sha_5 | Stable |
| sha_6 | Stable |
| sha_7 | Decrease |
| sha_8 | Stable |
| sha_8 | Stable |
| sha_9 | Decrease |
| sha_10 | Decrease |
| sha_11 | Increase |
| sha_12 | Stable |

Any solution?

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far and what did or did not work ? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose I read the data from my csv file:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\Workbook1.xlsx')

keep = []
for i in range(1, len(df) - 1):
    previous = df.loc[i-1, "bug"]
    current = df.loc[i, "bug"]
    next = df.loc[i+1, "bug"]

    if previous != "Stable" or current != "Stable" or next != "Stable":
        keep.append(i)

keep.append(i + 1)

df = df.filter(items=keep, axis=0)

print(df)
```

Is this what you expect to have?